# Why can't I use SoapClient::multiCall on my server?

Tags: php, soap, magento

I am writing some php code for interfacing with a magento server and am trying to group my soap calls.

The [magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/introduction) suggests the use of SoapClient::multiCall and I am able to get that to work fine on my home machine.

But If I try the exact same code on my server it tells me:
SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("multiCall") is not a valid method for this service

The [php manual for SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) doesn't even list multiCall as a method.

My home machine is running php version: PHP 5.3.3
While the server is running version: PHP 5.2.14

I'm at a loss for what's happening here any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code I'm running:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_location);  
$session = $client->login($user, $pass);
$client->multiCall($session, array(
        array(catalog_category.currentStore),
        array(catalog_category.currentStore)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I feel like a fool, it was a problem with the WSDL.

I was using different WSDLs on my home machine and server.

When I changed the URL from:
http://yourmagentohost/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1

to:
http://yourmagentohost/magento/api/?wsdl

You'll notice that I didn't have the /magento/ in my original URL.

Comment: The great thing about SOAP is once you've checked and rechecked everything that it's possible to check and feel like every avenue is exhausted, there's still **plenty** of places to check.